# How to start with skinr module in drupal

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am now working with skinr module in drupal. **As i am a newbie i can't able to get how it works and what is the starting point of skinr.**

I have read the documentation. But i need to some more thing which is very easy to understand. **For example i need something like step by step guide example.**

I googled. But i didn't find my requirement.

Any help will be thankful and grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few links to take a look at and get you started:

- http://groups.drupal.org/skinr
- http://sf2010.drupal.org/conference/sessions/theming-skinr
- http://www.amandarodriguez.com/blog/skinr-how-do-i-use-thing
- http://www.archive.org/search.php?query=skinr